# Is it possible to reference properties of another Model Element?

Tags: xtext

Ok, probably title does not mean too much sense but I could not figure out how to express my problem.

I am trying to design a dsl that will create Java Bean and also a Mapper for the Java Bean, it will look like the following...

```
Model:
  (elements+=AbtractModelElement)*;

AbstractModelElement:
  Bean | BeanMapper;

Bean:
  'bean' name=ID
  'fields' (fields+=BeanField)+;

BeanField:
  name=ID
  (type=FieldType);

enum FieldType:
  String='STRING' | BOOLEAN='BOOLEAN' | BYTE='BYTE';

BeanMapper:
   'mapper' name=ID
   'from'=[Bean]
   'to'=[Bean]
   'mappings' (mappings+=BeanMappingField)+;

BeanMappingField:
   (fieldFrom=[BeanField])
   ('<=' fieldTo=[BeanField]);
```

As you can see, nothing to fancy..

My model will look like the following

```
bean BeanA
   fields
      fieldA STRING
      fieldB BOOLEAN

bean BeanB
   fields
      fieldC BOOLEAN
      fieldD STRING
```

now the problem lies in the following part...

```
mapper beanAToBeanB
   from=BeanA
   to=BeanB
      mappings
         BeanA.fieldA <= BeanB.fieldD
         BeanA.fieldB <= BeanB.fieldC
```

I guess you can see the problem, while I don't want the user write random, not existing Field names, I use the notation 'BeanA.fieldA' but XText does not manage to resolve BeanA.fieldA.

I tried

```
fieldA <= fieldD
```

in the hope that XText can resolve over the name=ID structure of the BeanField, but that does not work also....

Is what I am trying to achieve is doable at all, if yes how?

Thx for answers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider` as described in https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/07/16/iqualifiednameproviders-in-xtext-2.0/